# EF Core Fluent API (How to remove identity from primary key)

Tags: ef-core-2.1

Seems simple but I can't figure out how to tell EF core not to create the primary key of an entity with an auto-incrementing identity column.  I want to insert my own primary key values myself. I realize I can do this using attributes, but I'd like to know how to set behavior via fluent API.  I see the UseSqlServerIdentityColumn() method from the Property() method but I need to turn it off (not on).  I've also tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Employees ON");
context.SaveChanges();
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Employees OFF");
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>()
    .Property( et => et.Id )
    .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Comment: As of EFCORE 5, this does not work. Doing so results in the error: "To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated."

Comment: That’s a problem with the generated migration code; the code in this answer is still the appropriate solution for configuring the model.  This answer provides a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56648859/1464084

Comment: Kevingy is right. I am creating a brand new DB and I this "ValueGeneratedNever()" has no effect at all. I deleted the database several times, and every single time it is recreated with Identity ON. The proposed workaround does not work for me (EF Core 5.0.11 & MSSQL 2016 SP1).

Comment: If I am not wrong, you have use SQL command... above command only work for creation (perfect for EF Core migration)

Answer (score 3):

With attribute it is also possible.

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```