# Updating Database in IdentityServer4IdentityCore Quickstart

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an asp.net mvc project running with an another IdentityServer4 (Quickstart including Identity Core support) and I just Can't update the Database, either seed it. I'm working with Core.

I followed [this tuto](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html)

So first, I'm not able to update de DB, I got this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: To change the IDENTITY property of a
> column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(AlterColumnOperation
> operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__71_4(MigrationsSqlGenerator
> g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation
> operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation
> operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1
> operations, IModel model)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration
> migration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass15_2.b__2()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs
> to be dropped and recreated.

Second thing, I realised that the seed methode in startup.cs doesn't work, seed return a false

> try
> {
> var seed = args.Contains("/seed");
> if (seed)
> {
> args = args.Except(new[] { "/seed" }).ToArray();
> }
>
> ```
>             var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
>
>             if (seed)
>             {
>                 Log.Information("Seeding database...");
>                 var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
>                 var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
>                 SeedData.EnsureSeedData(connectionString);
>                 Log.Information("Done seeding database.");
>                 return 0;
>             }
> ```

I don't know if someone has already use that tutoriel, but some help will be realy apprecieted :p Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to delete the database and recreate it, then it will work.

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408175/change-the-identity-property-of-a-column-the-column-needs-to-be-dropped-and-rec) pretty sums up the pain and suffering EntityFramework core will give you in production.

Comment: I already this option several times, never worked out.
I'm gona look to your link, maybe It will work. Thank for the reply ;)

Comment: if you delete the database, then it should work. if not it sounds like you have several independent migrations that all try to change the same database column.

Comment: Yup, indeed I had an another migration making all not working ! thx