# Id is always 0 when creating a new Order

Tags: asp.net-core, repository

I'm working with .net Core 5 and MVC
I'm trying to create a form to fill out Customer information to proceed with Ordering, everything is fine but the order Id generated is always 0. I Don't know where the problem lies. Can someone help me with the problem I'm having?

Here is my Repository

```
public bool CreateOrder(Order order)
    {
        var newOrder = new Order
        {
            FirstName = order.FirstName,
            LastName = order.LastName,
            Email = order.Email,
            PhoneNumber = order.PhoneNumber,
            //more
        };
        _dbContext.Orders.Add(newOrder);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my Post method

```
public IActionResult CreateOrder(Order order)
    {
        var items = _cartRepo.GetCartItem();
        if (items == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Add Product First");
        }
        else
        {
            _cartRepo.CreateOrder(order);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Model

```
 public partial class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
   // More
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code of the view that make the `POST` and the controller code that  renders the view. Point to the line generation `Id` equal 0, please?

Comment: So the problem wasn't in my code, it crashed when I had some Migration problems

Answer (score 1):

Do you use SSMS? If yes, go to the menu <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Designers</kbd> and uncheck *Prevent Saving changes that require table re-creation*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing this in your `createOrder` view inside the form:-

```
<input hidden asp-for="Id" />
```

Comment: Looks like my migration is having problem, now i get the following message: To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408175/change-the-identity-property-of-a-column-the-column-needs-to-be-dropped-and-rec  please follow this instruction.

Comment: I'm following it.

Comment: @SinLee simply drop(Delete) your DB and all migration. and and then ```add-migration <migration_name>``` and then ```update-database```

Comment: So the problem wasn't in my code, it crashed when I had some Migration problems

Comment: @SinLee so have you solved this problem by following the above link?

Comment: I fixed my Migration myself, adding Order was successful, but I don't understand why creating OrderDetails at the same time it gives conflict

Comment: Can you share the relationship of Order and OrderDetails,and share how do you create OrderDetails at the same time?