# Multiple Objects stored in database ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Can I make the below changes to my databse whilst maintaining the one-to-many relationship? Would my Airport class need to change at all?

Existing `Flight` class:

```
    public class Flight
    {
        public int FlightId { get; set; }
        public int DepartureAirportId { get; set; }
        public int ArrivalAirportId { get; set; }
        public DateTime FlightDateTime { get; set; }
        public int FlightDurationHours { get; set; }
        public Airport Airport { get; set; }
    }
```

Proposed new `Flight` class:

```
    public class Flight
    {
        public int FlightId { get; set; }
        public Airport DepartureAirport { get; set; }
        public Airport ArrivalAirport { get; set; }
        public DateTime FlightDateTime { get; set; }
        public int FlightDurationHours { get; set; }
    }
```

Airport class:

```
    public class Airport
    {
     
        public int AirportId { get; set; }
        public string AirportCode { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("DepartureAirportId")]
        public ICollection<Flight> Flight { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm unsure if having two objects of Airport in the same model will make the one-to-many relationships fail?

Comment: Did you try it? It looks fine to me.

Comment: No, I wanted some reassurance it would work as I have to re-seed the database again... I will try it thanks :)

Comment: Getting this error `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Airport.Flight' of type 'ICollection<Flight>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Comment: Think about how you would model that in the database. How is a flight assigned to an airport? You need departure AND arrival flights as separate things.

Comment: I see, so I would have a `DepartureAirport` model and `ArrivalAirport` model?

Comment: No, but you would probably have a list of `Departures` and a list of `Arrivals` in your airport and you would need to configure EF to link those to the relevant `DepartureAirportId` and `ArrivalAirportId`

Comment: Ok, I'll have a go at this. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239323/discussion-between-christian-and-davidg).

Answer (score 0):

Making changes to "production" databases with relationships and foreign keys via Entity Framework (or similar frameworks) is hard when you are making quite fundamental changes.

You really need to understand the underlying DB changes and table structures involved. Although you can abstract the DB when using EF and see a code view to a good extent, when making changes relying on a framework to make those those changes for you to your REAL data is something I have personally leaned away from.

I have posted about this topic before - [Change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408175/change-the-identity-property-of-a-column-the-column-needs-to-be-dropped-and-rec/60688578#60688578)