# C# Identity Server want to change Id Property of AspNetUserClaims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

im using a microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore as login/register in my app. When i added 2 custom Tables and added a new Migration there where 2 more changes to the identity Tables.

`migrationBuilder.AlterColumn(
name: "Id",
table: "AspNetUserClaims",
type: "int",
nullable: false,
oldClrType: typeof(int),
oldType: "int")
.Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");

```
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            type: "int",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int")
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");`
```

the problem is now i get an eception saying:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.'

Can someone help me here ? Why are these two Tables changed suddenly ? what can i do to migrate this ? (i dont really care about the data atm)

I tried removing the last Migration and adding it again same Result.
Tried to find an answer online why it suddenly Alters the column. and how i could revert it with no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408175/change-the-identity-property-of-a-column-the-column-needs-to-be-dropped-and-rec)

Comment: no it doesnt, because i dont even know why these two Tables where changed in the first place. Ideally i want to know how to undo these two changes

Comment: Have you checked the corresponding column in original AspNetRoleClaims table and migration history of `AspNetRoleClaims` entity to find if any updates on it. Besides, if these generated migration file include expected updates on some entities, you can modify or remove specific code snippets then do migrate to update to db.