Error "To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated."
I'm a beginner and i am having this error when i use the update-data base, after the migration:
"To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated."
And I'm not sure what to do
Here is my model:

>     public class ModelTraceType
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Class { get; set; }
    }
}

EntityConfigTraceType:
{
    public class EntityConfigTraceType : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TraceType>
    {
        private const string TableName = "TRACE_TYPE";
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TraceType> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable(TableName);
            //builder
            //.HasKey(p => p.Type)
            //.IsClustered();

            builder
            .HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .IsClustered();

            builder
                .Property(p => p.Type)
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Property(p => p.Class)
                .IsRequired();


            builder
builder
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .IsRequired()
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); // Explicitly marks the Id as an auto-incrementing field
                .Property(p => p.Type)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(TraceType.TypeLength);


Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408175/change-the-identity-property-of-a-column-the-column-needs-to-be-dropped-and-rec
